# Facebook Social Plugins - GDPR

Tags: javascript, facebook

I need to add a Facebook Page Plugin to a website and I couldn't find any information from FB's side on this specific element.

But how to handle pages that use the Facebook Page Plugin code on their site in terms of GDPR?

If I read the Page Plugin FAQ page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#faq_574746276036649

It seems to me that they get identifiable information, which on my side would require to ask the user for consent.
Besides generating the html code through JS, how would one conditionally load this plugin code then?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FB.XFBML.parse()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) to parse the plugin after adding it dynamically. You can also already add the div and load the JS SDK later - which would be the smarter idea, because then there is no connection to Facebook before the user accepts it.